# how to generate a div on the top of the page from javascript after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom, html, position

I am trying to generate a div element in the corner of the screen from a bookmarklet.

I tried

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id="blabal";
newdiv.style.background = "#00C";
newdiv.style.border = "4px solid #000";
newdiv.style.width=300;
newdiv.style.heigth=200;
newdiv.style.position="fixed";
newdiv.style.top="20";
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

to now avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide `px` with the values, and you got a typo in `heigth`:

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id="blabal";
newdiv.style.background = "#00C";
newdiv.style.border = "4px solid #000";
newdiv.style.width="300px";
newdiv.style.height="200px";
newdiv.style.position="fixed";
newdiv.style.top="20px";
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/gy9XJ/

Comment: Thanks Bryan and Niklas. Accepted for the example in the jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly accurate, but you have a typo in `height` and you need to provide units for `width`, `height` and `top`. I'm assuming pixels, but the interpreter won't be so kind; `200` could be in ems, pixels, points, percents (`200em`, `200px`, `200pt` and `200%`, respectively):

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.id="blabal";
newdiv.style.background = "#00C";
newdiv.style.border = "4px solid #000";
newdiv.style.width="300px";
newdiv.style.height="200px";
newdiv.style.position="fixed";
newdiv.style.top="20px";
document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
```